# Angular Unhandled Promise rejection: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included

Tags: angular

When I run my angular app I get error. Although I added BrowserModule to AppModule , I have get this error:[enter image description here]

My ApModule is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppAsideModule,
    AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
    AppFooterModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    AppSidebarModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    DeventreModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ToastModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_CONTAINERS,
    P404Component,
    P500Component,
    LoginComponent,
    SigninComponent
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
    [enter image description here][1]
```

Why do I get this error? Do you have any idea?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9YfD.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ...APP_CONTAINERS,
      P404Component,
      P500Component,
      LoginComponent,
      SigninComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      AppAsideModule,
      AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
      AppFooterModule,
      AppHeaderModule,
      AppSidebarModule,
      PerfectScrollbarModule,
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      TabsModule.forRoot(),
      ChartsModule,
      DeventreModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      NgbModule,
      TooltipModule,
      ToastModule,
      ConfirmDialogModule
    ],
    providers: [{
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
  })
```

Comment: It does not change anything